# Using Lambda/API Gateway in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I have a frontend that I designed in ReactJS on AWS Amplify with my Senior Project team and am looking to bring in data from API Gateway. I have a link I deployed that I tested in Lambda on the AWS console which works correctly. I am looking for some guidance on pulling in the data from that url to the frontend to use for a list. I can supply more information if you would like, please let me know what you need and any tips would be great! Thank you.

Comment: so, you tested api gateway from console, did you try calling api gateway endpoint from postman?

Comment: @BaluVyamajala Yes both worked correctly. What library would be best for sending queries to the endpoint to populate the frontend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assumption :**

As mentioned in your question i assume that you already aware how to create API Gateway,deploy API and now you have API gateway url to access rest API.

**Fetch data into react  :**

Example you have following cruds API

```
     GET /students         List all students
     GET /students/1       Load a studentsby id
     POST /students        Create a students
     PUT /students         Update a students
     DELETE /students/1    Delete a students by id
```

[image]

**Fetching data:**

```
           import { API } from 'aws-amplify';
             API.get('students', '/students', {}).then(result => {
             this.todos = JSON.parse(result.body);
              }).catch(err => {
                 console.log(err);
              })
```

**Security :**

You need to secure rest API either use API key or Authorizer

[image]

- https://github.com/vaquarkhan/aws-amplify-workshop-react
- https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/going-serverless-with-react-and-aws-amplify-part-2-creating-and-using-serverless-services-d401ba346eeb/
- https://gerard-sans.medium.com/create-a-rest-api-integrated-with-amazon-dynamodb-using-aws-amplify-and-vue-5be746e43c22

Comment: This is just what I needed! Thank you @vaquar-khan

Comment: Can I somehow import generated js SDK from API Gateway into my react application? I saw suggestions to use bundlers, But I don't know how exactly.